# How do I find the Authentication Domain Controller through Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, domaincontroller

I am trying to test authentication of various users to the Domain Controllers using Test-ADAuthentication command in powershell. However, I want to figure out how can I find which DC authenticated the user?

My current PS script is as follows:

```
Function Test-ADAuthentication 
{
    param(
        $username,
        $password)
    
        $DomainDN = ([adsi]'').distinguishedName
        $Account = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://$DomainDN",$UserName,$Password)
        [bool]$Account.distinguishedName
}


$list = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$Password = "notpassword1234$"

for($i=1; $i -le 779; $i++) 
{
    $userName = 'user' + $i
    $list.Add($userName)
}


foreach($username in $list){

    Test-ADAuthentication -username $username -password $password
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that information be available in the eventlog of the client the user is logged on?

Comment: `$env:logonserver` (this one we had issues when running from an elevated prompt so we ran it on a regular ps session). The, `Get-ADDomainController` should give you the same results. It's also listed in the registry

Comment: Wouldn't env:logonserver give the AD server that the host is logged on to instead of the user being tested by Test-ADAuthentication?